# Change aot metdata.json file generated directory when building library with ng-packagr

Tags: angular, angular2-aot, ng-packagr

I have created an Angular library. I'm using ng-packagr to build the library. When I am building the library with ng-packagr it creates the .metada.json for AOT in the directory where the public_api.ts file exists.

Can we change the .metdata.json generated directory to be inside the 'dist' folder?

> ng-package.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "public_api.ts",
    "languageLevel": [
      "dom",
      "es2017"
    ]
  },
  "whitelistedNonPeerDependencies": [
    "@angular/*",
    "core-js",
    "rxjs",
    "zone.js",
    "moment",
    "aws-sdk"
  ]
}
```

> tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "declaration": false,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es7",
      "dom"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "node",
      "jasmine"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
    "strictMetadataEmit": true,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: If you change metadata.json, your changes won't persist when you do npm install next time. It will get overridden. You can move those package inside src folder and import from there.

Comment: I actually don't want to change the content of the metadata.json file. I want the metadata.json file to be generated inside a folder named 'dist' when the library is built using 'ng-packagr -p ng-package.json' command. Current it is generated along with the source files in 'src' directory. Thanks.

Comment: can you share the ngPackgr `ng-package.json` configuration? It should create those stuff inside the output folder

Comment: @VivekKumar I updated the question with ng-package.json and ts-config.json

Answer (score 1):

If you creating this project from start and using the latest angular version or even angular version 5, Then I would suggest you use Nx Workspace.

It make this angular package creation process very simple,